# Serilog - How to stop request life cycle logs and enable only custom Information logs

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog, serilog-exceptions

I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1, I have included the nuget for serilog "Serilog.AspNetCore" version 3.2.0.

Configured to log to a file as below:

```
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
       .MinimumLevel.Information()
       .WriteTo.File("C:\\ProgramData\\MySolution\\MyLog.txt",
          rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
          fileSizeLimitBytes: 2000,
          retainedFileCountLimit: 5)
       .CreateLogger();
```

In my code I log using the code `Log.Information("Starting up");`

When I view the log I get a lot of data regarding the requests which I really don't need to see in the log

Example:

> 2020-03-18 12:19:27.355 +05:30 [INF] Content root path: C:\R\Path\MyProject.Notification
>
> 2020-03-18 12:19:27.486 +05:30 [INF] Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44360/swagger/index.html
>
> 2020-03-18 12:19:27.707 +05:30 [INF] Request finished in 227.3113ms 200 text/html;charset=utf-8
>
> 2020-03-18 12:19:27.909 +05:30 [INF] Requeststarting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44360/swagger/v1/swagger.json
>
> 2020-03-18 12:19:28.064 +05:30 [INF] Request finished in 154.5787ms 200 application/json;charset=utf-8
>
> 2020-03-18 12:19:41.221 +05:30 [INF] Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44360/Client/Index
>
> 2020-03-18 12:19:41.238 +05:30 [INF] Authorization was successful.

I really don't need all this log but I only want to log the ones which I specify using a `Log.Information("log content")` in side my controllers action methods.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: https://nblumhardt.com/2019/10/serilog-in-aspnetcore-3/ ?

Comment: @RubenBartelink Thank you Ruben the "MinimumLevel.Override" did the trick. But I had to specify one each for AspNetCore and EntityFrameworkCore. There was a another attribute as "Filter" but I'm still to get the hang of it.

Comment: cool - self answer with that, @ me here and you have an upvote from me (after which I will remove this message)

Answer (score 2):

As indicated with the link by Ruben, add the override for AspNetCore as follows:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore", LogEventLevel.Warning)
```

This will suppress a lot of unwanted messages.